# Making the UITextField analyze individual characters typed in rather than as a whole in Xcode Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to make a program that can convert the characters typed in to `UITextField1` into binary code in `UITextField2` with a click of a button. So far, when typing in one letter at a time I am able to successfully get the program to work. For example, if I type the letter `"a"` into `UITextField1` and click the convert button, it converts it to `"01100001"` into `UITextField2` with no problem. But if I then try to type in a combination of different letters like `"ab"` or `"ba"`, the program won't know what to do.
To cover all possible combinations of characters that can be typed in at one time, I was thinking it would be most appropriate to do something like have the `UITextField` analyze and convert each character one at a time.
Below is the Swift code I am working with in Xcode 7.3.1 and  a screenshot of the program when running.

Hopefully what I am trying to accomplish isn't too hard to do. I'm still pretty new to programming too so please forgive me.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var theLetters = ["a", "b"]
var theBinary = ["01100001", "01100010"]
var x = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var letters: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var binary: UITextField!


       @IBAction func toBinary(sender: UIButton) {

        if (theLetters[x] == letters.text) {
            binary.insertText(theBinary[x])
        }

        if (theLetters[x+1] == letters.text) {
            binary.insertText(theBinary[x+1])
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
    func hexToBinary(hex: String) -> String{
        let value = Int(hex, radix: 16)!
        return String(value, radix: 2)
    }

    func binaryToHex(binary: String) -> String{
        let value = Int(binary, radix: 2)!
        return String(value, radix: 16)
    }
```

Now you can try invoke `hexToBinary` in `toBinary`, and there will be no need for these two dictionaries `theLetters`, `theBinary`(because we can not map all the binaries and hexes).

Please comment if you have any other question, thanks.